# Powershell script to monitor in the background for a process and to end it if it runs

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a powershell script to monitor in the background for a process to fire, if this does run the script will kill it.

Snario:
Deploying an application via SCCM however the script hangs because of a child licensing process which runs at the very end of the application installation. ( I need a powershell command to monitor for this process and to end it allowing the script to end with an exit=0.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have silent install switches to bypass such prompts during installation.
Please provide more details like the name, version of the software you are trying to install
If it is an msi package or an exe, command line used for installation

Comment: the application installs fully silent ok, The issue is that the powershell script running the application hangs  as it detects a child process running at the very end of the install, what I need to do is kill this process which in turn will also allow the script to end. So I am looking for a powershell command to capture this process running and end it when it spawns.

Answer (score 0):

Get-process | Stop-Process will end process

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-process -Name "Process"| Stop-Process -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

kills the process at the beginning of the script but it needs to monitor the system processes in the background and auto kill the process if it respawns again whilst still processing the script.